# I have link error with OpenCV and XCode4.2

Tags: opencv, hyperlink, i386

I'm trying to link OpenCV in my iPhone project. I upgraded project made on Xcode3.x for latest Xcode. So I need to link opencv built on Xcode 4.3.

I followed the guide in http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en.

But I meet the link error like below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_dgesdd_", referenced from:
      cv::_SVDcompute(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat*, cv::Mat*, int) in libopencv_core.a(lapack.o)
  "_sgesdd_", referenced from:
      cv::_SVDcompute(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat*, cv::Mat*, int) in libopencv_core.a(lapack.o)
  "_dpotrf_", referenced from:
      cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int) in libopencv_core.a(lapack.o)
      cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int) in libopencv_core.a(lapack.o)
......
```

I wonder I never configured i386 architecture. Please tell me how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found that I missed Accelerate.framework in Build Phase.

You can add framework in [Project]->[Build Phases]->[Link Binary With Libraries].

Comment: Ok, select this answer as the official when you can. Just click on the checkbox near it. I think you have to wait 48hrs before you can do so. Welcome to Stackoverflow.